# Dynamicly added Controls [e.g Button] : How to add events and Access

Tags: c#, controls

At my program i dynamicly add Buttons to my form

```
{
   ...
   Button bt = new Button();
   bt.Text = "bla bla";
   bt.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(bt_MouseClick);
   myPanel.Controls.Add(bt);
   ... 
}

void bt_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TabPage _tab = new TabPage();
    _tab.Text =  ??? // I want to get the Button's text ! this.Text returns me the
                     //main form.Text 
}
```

How can access my dynamic Buttons properties ? How can I understand whick button is 
clicked either getting its text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an [`EventHandler` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) is invoked, the `sender` parameter is the component that raised the event, and the `e` parameter is a subclass of `EventArgs` that provides any additional component/event specific information for the event.

Therefore you can establish which button the event fired on by casting the `sender` parameter to `Button`:

```
void bt_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    TabPage _tab = new TabPage();
    _tab.Text =  button.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void bt_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TabPage _tab = new TabPage();
    _tab.Text =  ((Button)sender).Text;
}
```